# C# WindowsForms ООП (помогите с пунктами 4 и 5)

Tags: c#, ооп

(ВОПРОСЫ СНИЗУ)

Задание:
1) Определить класс Student, который имеет:

- закрытое поле типа string, в котором хранятся данные студента;
- закрытое поле типа string для информации о форме обучения;
- закрытое поле типа int для номера группы;
- закрытое поле типа int [] для информации об оценках (5 оценок) на экзаменах, которые получил студент.

2) В классе Student определить конструкторы:

- конструктор c параметрами типа string, int, int [] для инициализации полей класса;
- конструктор без параметров, инициализирующий поля класса значениями по умолчанию.

3) В классе Student определить свойства c методами get и set:

- свойство типа string для доступа к полю с данными студента;
- свойство типа string для доступа к полю с формой обучения;
- свойство типа int для доступа к полю с номером группы;
- свойство типа int [] для доступа к полю со списком оценок экзаменов.

4) В классе Student определить:

- свойство типа double (только с методом get), в котором вычисляется средний балл как среднее значение оценок в списке сданных экзаменов;
- метод void Add () для добавления нового студента;
- перегруженную версию виртуального метода string ToString() для формирования строки со значениями всех полей класса, включая список оценок;
- метод string ToShortString(), который формирует строку со значениями всех полей класса без списка оценок, но со значением среднего балла.

5) В обработчике события загрузке формы:

- Создать 4 объекта типа Student.
- Преобразовать данные в текстовый вид с помощью метода ToShortString() и вывести данные.
- Преобразовать данные в текстовый вид с помощью метода ToString() и вывести данные.
- Интерфейс разработать по своему усмотрению.

Я сделал 1-3 пункты. Заранее спасибо!

```
    class Student
    {
        private string info;
        private string form;
        private int groupNumber;
        private int[] marks = new int[4];

        public Student(string i, string f)
        {
            info = i;
            form = f;
        }

        public Student(int gN, int[] m)
        {
            groupNumber = gN;
            marks = m;
        }

        public Student()
        {
            info = "Carl Johnson";
            form = "Full-Time";
            groupNumber = 2;
            marks[0] = 5;
            marks[1] = 3;
            marks[2] = 4;
            marks[3] = 5;
        }

        public string Info
        {
            get
            {
                return info;
            }
            set
            {
                info = value;
            }
        }

        public string Form
        {
            get
            {
                return form;
            }
            set
            {
                form = value;
            }
        }

        public int GroupNuber
        {
            get
            {
                return groupNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                groupNumber = value;
            }
        }

        public int[] Marks
        {
            get
            {
                return marks;
            }
            set
            {
                marks = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

### Вопросы:

- Как сделать перегруженную версию виртуального метода string ToString()?
- Я написал так, но не знаю, правильно ли?

  ```
  public override string ToString()
  {
      return Convert.ToString(MessageBox.Show($"ФИО: {info}\n Форма обучения: {form}\n Номер группы: {groupNumber}\n Оценки: {marks}\n"));
  }
  ```
- Правильно ли я сделал пункт с методом ToShortString()?

  ```
  public string ToShortString()
  {
      return Convert.ToString(MessageBox.Show($"ФИО: {info}\n Форма обучения: {form}\n Номер группы: {groupNumber}\n Средний балл: {(marks[0] + marks[1] + marks[2] + marks[3]) / 4}"));
  }
  ```
- Как именно нужно создать 4 объекта типа Student?
- И как преобразовать данные в текстовый вид с помощью метода ToShortString() и ToString() и вывести данные?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93752/discussion-on-question-by-default-c-windowsforms-----4--5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задание 1.

- У вас в требовании 5 оценок, на данный момент вы ввели 4.

Задание 2.

- У вас в требованиях конструктор с параметрами string, int, int [].
- У вас в коде его нет, зато есть два лишних: public Student(string i, string f) и public Student(int gN, int[] m).

Задание 3.

- Тут ошибок не вижу.

Задание 4.

- Советую почитать и разобрать примеры по свойствам: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.4.php
- Метод toString() и toShortString()

Идея правильная, реализация неправильная.

1. Вам нужно вернуть строку, вы же вызываете MessageBox.Show(...) и приводе к строке его вывод, получив текст "ОК". Вам нужен только возврат строки без MessageBox.Show(...);
2. Вам нужно вернуть оценки, но просто вставив $".... {marks}" вы получите в итоге ".... System.Int[32]" поскольку массив при таком подходе не вернет список своих значений. Попробуйте пройтись в цикле по массиву и склеить строку.

Не забывайте, что можете писать в методах и свойствах более сложный код (просто пример):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        str += i + " ";
    }
    return str;
}
```

Задание 5.
Дальше вам надо создать на форме многостраничное текстовое поле.
В графическом конструкторе определить событие Load: https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/2.4.php
Перейти в код формы и создать там массив из 4 объектов Student, как вы делали это с массивом чисел в задании 1.
Дальше вывести в текстовое воле все значения toString() объектов Student.

Попробуйте реализовать это по порядку и если какой-либо пункт не получится, то создайте отдельный вопрос. По крайней мере в вопросах вас никто не ограничивает, но если задавать их всем скопом в рамках одного вопроса, то выходят достаточно громоздкие ответы.

Comment: 1 и 2 исправил, но некоторые вопросы всё равно есть. Как вернуть только строку? Как именно нужно пройтись в цикле по массиву? В пятом я сделал следующее:
        private void Task11_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] students = new int[3];
            listBox1.Items.Add(students.ToString());
        }

Comment: @Default убрать лишние `Convert.ToString(MessageBox.Show(...))` оставив только `return $"....";`.